# How do I reference a file from a relative path at runtime, not compile time

Tags: java, file

I have a class file located at:

> `src/test/java/suites/suite/MyClass.Java`

I also have a resource file located at:

> `src/test/resources/suites/suite/myresource.txt`

The resource is generated via below method:

```
private void generateFile(String filepath) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    outputStream.write(encodedString);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

I need to access that file at a later point in the code but I get a `NullPointerException` at the following code line:

```
new File(getClass().getResource("/suites/suite/myresource.txt").toURI();
```

This is because the file didn't exist during compilation. How do I reference a file from a relative path in this case? I have it working using the absolute path but I need to make this generic.

Comment: it is not possible to put the file in server

Comment: Write/read the file to `./whatever`, not something in the `src` directory.

Comment: [edit] your question and post the code that generates file `myresource.txt`

Comment: @Abra, sure, please see edit section above, thanks.

Comment: Why not save the `filepath` argument to method `generateFile()` ?

Comment: @Abra, I've re-described above, I guess I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
new File("/suites/suite/myresource.txt").getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: I had to prefix 'src/test/resources' though to get it resolved, thanks.

Comment: @LP Then this doesn't solve your problem in any way. It is still referring to a compile time path that won't be there at runtime. The `getCanonicalPath()` part adds nothing useful.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, but what do you mean? .getCanonicalPath() resolves the absolute pathname. The OP asked about how he can reference a relative file. This does.